# How do I open a pdf file in the TexMaker internal PDF viewer using a user-defined quick build sequence?

Tags: pdf, texmaker

I'm trying to write a document with a bibliography, and none of the default Quick Build presets have a BibTex parsing step. It's easy enough to make a sequence of commands that run PdfLaTeX, BibTex, PdfLaTeX, PdfLaTeX, but I cannot see how to use the internal PDF viewer to then display the generated PDF file.

I saw that someone else [reported this same problem on the TexMaker issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=55) but the author appears to have just dismissed it as already implemented. I've tried calling `view %.pdf`, `view pdf`, `view pdf %.pdf` (as the person who originally reported the issue tired) and had about the same results. Calling `viewpdf` with or without arguments gives the exact same results (nothing).

I can easily just click "View PDF" in the toolbar after the build process has finished but it's extra interaction required on my part that should easily be avoidable...

Does anyone know what command I need to use in the user defined quick build section in order to launch the built in PDF viewer automatically?

I'm running TexMaker 3.0.2 on Windows 7 with MikTex 2.9. I also use TexMaker on Ubuntu 10.10 so something that will work cross platform would be great.

Comment: For anybody using the fork **TeXstudio** (formerly known as TexMakerX), the follow-up question [How do I open the internal viewer in a custom Quick Build command with TeXStudio or TeXMaker?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29208/how-do-i-open-the-internal-viewer-in-a-custom-quick-build-command-with-texstudio) might be of interest.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It may sound quite strange, but you have to use *exactly the same command* as you use to open the external PDF viewer! This is because the code to run the external programs (the function `Texmaker::RunCommand` located in `texmaker.cpp`, ll.5433-5596 in the [sources](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/texmaker-3.0.2.tar.bz2)) checks if the command to be executed is the PDF viewer, and runs the internal viewer instead of the external program if it is activated.

In order to use the internal PDF viewer, you have to select `Pdf Viewer->Built-in Viewer` <s>and *disable* the `Embed` checkbox</s> in the `Options->Configure Texmaker->Commands` menu. Now you'll be able to launch Texmaker's viewer by using the same command in the `Quick Build->User` input field as stated  in `Commands->Pdf Viewer->External Viewer`.

No program you use in your Quick Build command line must exit with an error, otherwise the execution will be aborted and the viewer won't be shown.

Comment: Wow. That is more than a little confusing :P. It works though, so thanks. I have left the PDF Viewer embedded and it is opening without issue.

Comment: Good job, diabonas.

Comment: How about your linux (e.g. Ubuntu) version of Texmaker?

Comment: @robguinness It should work as described in this answer, the implementation is the same for all platforms. I just checked with the latest Texmaker version 4.0.1 on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

Comment: Ok, I was using a much earlier version of Texmaker (installed using apt-get on Ubuntu 10.04). I upgraded to Texmaker 3.2.2 and now the Commands menu looks similar to the one you described.

Comment: It's working as you describe now, but what if I would actually like to use the "embed" feature? Is this possible using the Quick Build command?

Comment: It works also with the "Embed" enabled.

Comment: also worth noting: *exactly* means **exactly**. so no spaces between the command separator “|” and the command: “… | evince %.pdf” != “…|evince %.pdf”

Comment: @flyingsheep 's comment is incredibly important!  If you add extra spaces, it will open evince externally.  Thank you for pointing this out.