# View PDF result when using arara with TexMaker

Tags: texmaker, viewers, arara

This is a follow-up on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/integration-of-arara-in-texmaker). I was able to configure TexMaker correctly to use arara in my documents, but still there is a problem viewing the resultant PDF in the built-in viewer of TexMaker. Using an external viewer is easy, but I couldn't configure my editor to use the built-in viewer. I run MiKTex on Windows 7. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The embedded viewer expects the pdf to be in the same directory as the `masterfile.tex` file or the one in the window you compiled from.  So verify that you do have a pdf in the same folder and the base name must be the same ie `masterfile.pdf`.   The only option you have on the built-in viewer is whether to embed or have a separate window.

Comment: Yes, it is in the same directory and with the same name and I can open with the external viewer automatically, but I love the simple built in viewer which does not disrupt  my work flow.

Comment: Check all the logs because both TexMaker and TeXstudio will not start the embedded viewer is any errors (fatal or not) that have been reported by any preceding process in a quickbuild or sequential (arara command sequence).

Comment: The embedded viewer works in normal `Quickbuild` mode (PdfLaTeX+View PDF), which means there are no errors. I need to explicitly know what is the command which opens the embedded viewer in normal `Quickbuild` mode so that I can copy it to the `arara` sequence. I suspect it is `Gsview` ...

Comment: Having a pdf does not mean no errors, just not fatal errors.  The command  is demonstrated here in the first answer. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29208/how-do-i-open-the-internal-viewer-in-a-custom-quick-build-command-with-texstudio

Comment: @R.Schumacher (+1) Many thanks. That answer helped me and I was able to configure `arara` correctly. I added the very same external viewer command (this now reads: `arara %.tex|"C:/Program Files/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe" %.pdf`) to my `arara` user command and it worked. The only thing I observe now is that `arara` is much slower than when done the `Quickbuild` way.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can make this an answer or should I post my configuration settings now as answer?

Comment: Post it for youself with a screenshot of the configuration settings.  Then accept the answer.