# Tell Texmaker's internal/embedded pdf viewer to use "build" subdirectory

Tags: pdftex, biber, texmaker, ubuntu

I've recently discovered the "use 'build' subdirectory" option within Texmaker to get every compilation file neatly into one folder so it doesn't cluster the main folder. When I did that, biber suddenly threw errors and I quickly found out that this was due to biber not finding the *.bcf file anymore. I just changed `biber %` to `biber build/%` and that was fine.

However now the integrated pdf viewer doesn't find the pdf file anymore and that kind of bothers me. Yes, I can use an external one where I can specify in texmaker to use the `build/*.pdf` path, but I don't want that. I like using an integrated one.

I already tried attaching the command `cp build/*.pdf build/...` to my "complete" User command to compile my latex script with my .bib file and now it looks like this:

`pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | biber build/% | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | cp build/*.pdf build/..`

The copy command works fine in the terminal, but Texmaker seems to be having problem executing that one directly after the compilation.

Furthermore I tried from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29470/292641) to use `tmx:///view-pdf-internal`, but it didn't work

Do you have any where I can specify a/the location for the pdf viewer?

Thanks!

Comment: The best thing to do with your recently discovered "use build subdirectory"-option is to very quickly forget about it again. This causes way more problems than it solves.

Comment: I already deactivated it :') Very unfortunate