# How to add a new command to invoke ImageMagick in TeXMaker?

Tags: texmaker

[image]

How to add a new command to invoke ImageMagick in TeXMaker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under User --> User Commands you can add up to five custom commands.

[image]

Comment: Oh my, I saw `arara`! ♥

Comment: @HiggsBoson See if [How do I open a pdf file in the TexMaker internal PDF viewer using a user-defined quick build sequence?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17018/how-do-i-open-a-pdf-file-in-the-texmaker-internal-pdf-viewer-using-a-user-define) helps. I don't really use TeXmaker, and I'm not very familiar with customizing it.