# Ubuntu Texmaker won't update PDF with Quickbuild

Tags: texmaker, preview

I'm using TexMaker 4.4.1 together with TexLive in Ubuntu 16.04.

In TexMaker I can successfuly compile a document with XeLatex (pushing the button `xelatex`) and than show PDF output with the build-in viewer (pushing the button `View PDF`).

[image]

When I run `QuickBuild` option the document is successfuly compiled and the new PDF is created. However the PDF file in the build-in viewer will not update.

I have the following settings:
[image]

[image]

Simple question:
**How can I show the new PDF with build-in viewer after `QuickBuild` compilation?**

Comment: I'm using the same version of Texmaker on the same system, and after choosing the setting "XeLaTeX + Vie PDF" for Quick Build, pressing F1 or pushing Tools -> Quick Build compiles the document and refreshes the build-in PDF viewer.

Comment: The problem is it cannot load the PDF with `evince %.pdf` command (neither when choosing `External Viewer` or `Quickbuild` option). Although `evince` command works fine in terminal. I don't know what is happening in TexMaker.

Comment: So what is your problem now - that you can't open Evince, or that the built-in PDF viewer doesn't refresh?

Comment: That's the same thing according to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17018/how-do-i-open-a-pdf-file-in-the-texmaker-internal-pdf-viewer-using-a-user-define?rq=1).

Comment: No. Evince is the standard PDF viewer of Ubuntu, a program completely independent of Texmaker. The built-in PDF viewer of Texmaker is, as the description says, a built-in component of Texmaker displaying PDFs. It is displayed either in a separate window, or as a separate pane in the texmaker window.

Comment: Read the linked post. I think the `evince %.pdf` command makes somehow  the problem.

Comment: I have read the linked post. There is no mention that Evince and Internal View are the same. It says that one needs to trigger the same Texmaker command to open either - and that the options that you display below choose what happens. However, since you don't want to create your one chain of compilation command, but just try to do "XeTeX + View" (a predefined option), the linked post is unrelated to this problem. And since the setting you show works fine for me, I asked: What does exactly not work - the opening of Evince or the refreshing of the internal PDF-viewer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60530/discussion-between-user46581-and-tiuri).